# How to construct an efficient query that counts different attributes in different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a row with certain attributes in different columns. Column A can be 1 or 0. Column B can be ``, null or have a value.

I want to count the number of rows in the table that have Column A with a 1, the number of rows in the table that have Column B as `` or null, and the number of rows in Column B that have an entry not equal to '' and not equal to null.

Is it possible to put this all into a single query or do I have to write three different queries?

I am using mysql. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `B` condition will count all rows anyway so you could do it with a single scan.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN A=1 THEN 'X' END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN B='' OR B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN B='' OR B IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, should that 'X' in the first line be 1?

Comment: @Hardworker - No. `COUNT` counts all `NOT NULL` values so any arbitrary `NOT NULL` value will work. I deliberately avoided using 1 in case that gave the wrong impression. For the `SUM` version of course `1` is required.